# Returning results from database using IN array

Tags: asp-classic

I was wondering if someone could help me.

I have an array which is like this

```
fileArray = '2612(25).jpg', '2012(15).jpg', '2012(31).jpg', '2012(21).jpg', '2012(58).jpg'
```

Now i have the following code.

```
Set DBConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
DBConn.Open strOLEDBString, strODBCUser, strODBCPass

SQL = "SELECT p, sum(vote) as likes FROM vote WHERE p in (" & fileArray & ") GROUP BY p ORDER BY sum(vote) desc"

Set rs = DBConn.Execute(SQL)

If rs.eof Then
    HTMLTable = HTMLTable & " Nothing returned"
Else 
    HTMLTable = HTMLTable & rs("p")
End If
```

The results only show the last filename in the array, it should be displaying all of them.

Comment: I think you have an error here.  How can you take an array of a bunch of different strings and jam it into a space where only one string is expected?

Comment: Are u familiar with SQL IN statement?

Comment: @YuriyGalanter No im not

Comment: @YuriyGalanter-who are you asking?  If me, then, yes, I'm familiar with it.

Comment: @STLDeveloper then interpret what SQL string will have in it. BigJobbies your SQL is correct but you need to iterate thru results, see my answer below

Comment: @YuriyGalanter - `fileArray` isn't a string, but an array of strings.  I don't think you can stick an array into the middle of the SQL string concatenation and get out of it what is expected.  What this person needs here is a comma-separated concatenation of the fileArray's contents, which is what I proposed below.

Comment: @STLDeveloper Actually I beleive in this case it's a single string of comma separated values.

Comment: Well, given his recent comment regarding the SQL statement being emitted, I believe you're right.  However, looking at his question it's obviously not.  I'll chalk this up to a transcription error!  Should have been `fileArray = "'2612(25).jpg', '2012(15).jpg', '2012(31).jpg', '2012(21).jpg', '2012(58).jpg'"`. Oh well, I did the best I could with what I had to work with. Still don't believe my answer should be voted down due to OP's question being improperly stated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop thru ADO Recordset to get all the records:

```
...
Else
  Do While Not rs.eof
    HTMLTable = HTMLTable & "<tr><td>" & rs("p") & "</td></tr>"
    rs.MoveNext
  Loop
End If
```

Comment: Where do you assign initial value of HTMLTable? It should have at least the same result you did before, but possibly more. Depending on result returned by the query. How many records do u get if u run the query directly in DB?

Comment: Quite a few lines up, using HTMLTable = "<table border = 0 width=""100%"" >" & vbCRLF

Comment: I've modified my code taking into account this being a table, can u give it a try?

Comment: Opps ... My bad ... I forgot to add the 'Not' in the Do While statement doiiiiii .. That works perfect now ... Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You need "" around your filearray statement.

```
fileArray = "'2612(25).jpg', '2012(15).jpg', '2012(31).jpg', '2012(21).jpg', '2012(58).jpg'"
```